# How can I transfer data from iPhone to Windows 7 PC via USB cable?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, iphone

I want to transfer all the data from my iPhone to my Windows 7 PC. When I use a USB, the computer says that it can't install the drivers.

Is there any way to transfer this data on my computer?

Comment: What kind of data are you wanting to transfer?  Is iTunes installed on PC? iTunes would install drivers needed, but it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. How was the data stored?

Comment: USB access is limited via the standard windows explorer. If you want to access all data and not through iTunes, then try a program such as iexplorer - https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/  very thorough and has some great export functions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my iPhone.  The eventual fix was to remove iTunes and it's associated driver package that comes with it. I had to manually uninstall iTunes, QuickTime, Apple Software Update, Apple Mobile Device Support, Bonjour and Apple Application Support.  Reinstalled iTunes and I was able to copy back and forth from my iPhone.  You won't technically be able to transfer "all" of the "phones" data.  There are other solutions for that.  But if you are talking pictures and general stuff like that, this should do the trick.